# How to set a page to expire in AEM 6.1?

Tags: aem

I need to set a page to expire. I can see a property called "`expires`" for the DAM assets, but there is no such property for pages. How can I set it on a page?

Also, I need to send the notification to the administrators when the page is going to expire, let's say 5 days before the page is set to expire. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using a feature called '[Manage Publication](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/author/page-authoring/publishing-pages.html#Unpublishing%20from%20the%20Console)' in AEM. It allows you to unpublish a page immediately or schedule it for later. This is basically a scheduled job in the workflow which will ubpublish (deactivate/delete) your page from the publisher on a given time.

AEM 6.1 specific document can be found [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/publishing-pages.html#Publish/Unpublish%20Later%20-%20Touch-optimized%20UI).

Comment: Thanks i.net! Also, Can we send a notification to the admin before the page is set to expire?

Comment: I believe you can do it with some workflow customisation.